# How do you set the modification time of a file in a ClearCase vob?

Tags: clearcase

I have several files that I rsync'd over to the vob and they all have times 40 minutes in the future.
I tried touch, and all that does is maintain the time 40 minutes into the future from when I touch.

I guess that ClearCase is in charge of setting the modification time and is overriding touch.
Is there another way?  Is there a way to tell ClearCase to stop messing up the file time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What option did you use when adding those files to source control?

As explained in this [help page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_addtoctrl_ux.htm):

> To preserve the modification time of the file being checked in, use the `-ptime` option.
>   If you omit the `-ptime` option, the modification time of the new version is set to the checkin time.

The [`mkelem` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkelem.htm) adds:

> On some UNIX and Linux platforms, it is important that the modification time be preserved for archive files (libraries) created by `ar`(1) (and perhaps updated with `ranlib`(1)).
>   The link editor, `ld`(1), generates an error message if the modification time does not match a time recorded in the archive itself. Be sure to use this option, or (more reliably) store archive files as elements of a user-defined type, created with the `mkeltype –ptime` command. This causes `–ptime` to be invoked when the element is checked in.

Unless you remove those files and re-create them, I don't think you can change the ["Created on" time](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/u_props_elem.htm).